# How to set subscription every 2 Months or 3 Months in Square Payment Gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, subscription, square-connect

We're integrating Square Subscription API into our website. I've read the API Document. I've only find Monthly & weekly subscription. We want every 2 months, 3 months, 6 months & 12-month subscription also.
Is there any provision in Square Payment gateway for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cadence` of a `SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN` has `EVERY_TWO_WEEKS`, `THIRTY_DAYS`, `SIXTY_DAYS`, and `NINETY_DAYS`, among many others: https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/objects/CatalogObject#definition__property-subscription_plan_data.